# How to create a logout url for Azure Active Directory for SSO , Need suggestion

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on

I am working on a SSO Project where I am creating a SAML Auth Request for login and it is redirecting me to Microsoft Page and it is authenticating against Azure Active Directory which is working fine ,I have attached the code of preparation of SAML Request login .Now I have to prepare the code for logout in Azure Active directory ,can anyone help me with the preparation of Azure ACtive directory logout url in the similar way what we did for login. What changes needs to be done in the URL Request .For login in url we need to have SAMLRequest as a query string parameter ,for logout how the Url look like ?

```
SAML Auth Request LogIN URL (saml end point is the login url which we got)

 public string SSO(string samlEndpoint)
        {
            var queryStringSeparator = samlEndpoint.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?";

        var url = samlEndpoint + queryStringSeparator + "SAMLRequest=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.GetRequestSSO(AuthRequest.AuthRequestFormat.Base64));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relayState))
        {
            url += "&RelayState=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(relayState);
        }

        return url;


        }



  public string GetRequestSSO(AuthRequestFormat format)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xws))
            {
                xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "AuthnRequest", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("ID", _id);
                xw.WriteAttributeString("Version", "2.0");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("IssueInstant", _issue_instant);
                xw.WriteAttributeString("ProtocolBinding", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("AssertionConsumerServiceURL", _assertionConsumerServiceUrl);

                xw.WriteStartElement("saml", "Issuer", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
                xw.WriteString(_issuer);
                xw.WriteEndElement();

                xw.WriteStartElement("samlp", "NameIDPolicy", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("Format", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified");
                xw.WriteAttributeString("AllowCreate", "true");
                xw.WriteEndElement();
                xw.WriteEndElement();
            }

            if (format == AuthRequestFormat.Base64)


            {

                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                var writer = new StreamWriter(new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true), new UTF8Encoding(false));
                writer.Write(sw.ToString());
                writer.Close();
                string result = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
                return result;

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Gaucho ,can you help me

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-a-sign-out-request) sign out request url.

Comment: @HuryShen ,i am not using OAuth ,its SAML based SSO ,the microsoft documentation is confusing (not able to understand),,could you help with the code ,what modification I need to do in XML Preparation as attached above